# Date format without hour, minutes and seconds

Tags: python, datetime

I have following code:

```
import datetime
x = '2015-01-01'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(date)
```

The problem is that I want to print date like `"2015-01-01"` and not `"2015-01-01 00:00:00"`. How to print it without hours, minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime` objects have a [`date` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) which does this for you:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x = '2015-01-01'
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
>>> print(date.date())
2015-01-01
>>>
```